# How to connect to SphinQL Query Builder?

Tags: php, sphinxql

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 + PHP + Nginx + MySQL 5.6

My project path is /usr/share/nginx/www/project1

I've installed Sphinx successfully and able to connect thorough API. But I like to use SphinxQL Query Builder.

I am not familiar with composer and php namespace. I've installed composer  in my machine.

I copied the "SphinxQL-Query-Builder-master" folder to my project root directory.

Now I executed this

```
use Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL;
use Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection;

// create a SphinxQL Connection object to use with SphinxQL
$conn = new Connection();
$conn->setParams(array('host' => 'domain.tld', 'port' => 9306));

$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('column_one', 'colume_two')
->from('index_ancient', 'index_main', 'index_delta')
    ->match('comment', 'my opinion is superior to yours')
    ->where('banned', '=', 1);

$result = $query->execute();
```

This returns me Fatal error: Class 'Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection' not found

Can anyone help me step by step guide for this ?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Composer by itself is not requirement for your project, it is php package manager. You can install Foolz\SphinxQL library using this command:

```
php composer.phar require foolz/sphinxql-query-builder
```

If **composer.phar** does not exists in you project folder you can download it using:

```
php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php
```

After sucessfull installation SphinxQL library will be downloaded to **vendor** folder. Also you need to require autoload script generated by composer **vendor/autoload.php** and change **host/port** configuration before using it.

Finally your code example should look like this:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use Foolz\SphinxQL\SphinxQL;
use Foolz\SphinxQL\Connection;

// create a SphinxQL Connection object to use with SphinxQL
$conn = new Connection();
// Here sphinx installation host and port listening for Mysql connection 
$conn->setParams(array('host' => '127.0.0.1', 'port' => 9306));

$query = SphinxQL::create($conn)->select('column_one', 'colume_two')
    ->from('index_ancient', 'index_main', 'index_delta')
    ->match('comment', 'my opinion is superior to yours')
    ->where('banned', '=', 1);

$result = $query->execute();
```